# how to toggle certain jquery effects with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, effects

I want to be able to toggle certain effects in jquery by using javascript, is this code correct? and what would be the simplest solution?

P.s. dont say "use .toggle()", there is currently a bug with it that causes it to minimise the paragraph

**HTML**

```
<!--This first line calls in jquery-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello all</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    color: red;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 50px
}
```

**JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT**

```
var num = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").click(
    if (num == 0) {
        var num == 1;
    } else {
        var num == 0;);

    $("p").click(function () {
        if (num == 1) {
            $(this).animate({
                color: "black",
                backgroundColor: "white",
                fontFamily: "arial",
                fontSize: "20px",
                fontFamily: "serif"
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                color: "red",
                backgroundColor: "lightblue",
                borderRadius: "5px",
                height: "50px",
            }, 500);
        });
    });
```

Thank you all for your time i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is probably with a data attribute as a flag, and with ternarys in the object, like this

```
$('p').on('click', function() {
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    $(this).animate({
        color           : flag ? "red"     : "black",
        backgroundColor : flag ? "#ADD8E6" : "white",
        fontSize        : flag ? "20px"    : "10px",
        borderRadius    : flag ? "5px"     : "0px"
    });

    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vh5k9t01/)

Comment: This is a great answer! but i would also like to know why my code does not work? @adeneo

Comment: Your code does't work because it's full of syntax errors! You can't just write `$('p').click( if(this) that )` <- that's a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

As to why your code is not working, you are just using the wrong operators in your first click handler and not defining a function, the right code should be:

```
var num=0;

$(document).ready(function () {

$("p").click(function(){
    if (num == 0) {
        num = 1;
    } else {
        num = 0;
    }
});

$("p").click(function () {
    if (num == 1) {
        $(this).animate({
            color: "black",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            fontFamily: "arial",
            fontSize: "20px",
            fontFamily: "serif"
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            color: "red",
            backgroundColor: "lightblue",
            borderRadius: "5px",
            height: "50px",
            fontSize: "12px",
        }, 500);
    }
});

});
```

However I much prefer @adeneo's solution as it's more elegant and less verbose

Comment: Sorry, had some syntax error there, didn't test, fixed it up now. However this code would only work if you only have one 'p' element in your page as the num variable is global. If you have multiple 'p' element, @adeneo's solution is the way to go. (P.S: vanialla Jquery can't do color animation so using 'color' and 'background-color' won't work. There is however a plugin that enables this: [Jquery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) )

Comment: if you look closely at my html i have linked jquery ui which allows me to do color animations

Comment: Sorry didn't see that